# CSS fluid layout: "stacked" div with different heights

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to create a CSS layout where divs with `float: left` property would not create a new "row"-like layout but be really fluid.

To be more specific here's what I have now:

[image]

All blocks are `div` with `float: left` style, certain margins and unfixed height attribute. As you can see every high enough block forms a "line" or "row" with same height. What I'm trying to achieve is -- make all `div` element obey only their own `margin` style and not create a row with similar height.

So the question is if it's possible and if yes then how can it be achieved?

*HTML* (some blocks omitted):

```html
<div id="blocks_wrapper">
<div class="strblock rouded_3px infobox">
    <div class="dElement">
        <div class="d_option">Web</div>
        <div class="d_value"><a href="" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="strblock rouded_3px infobox">
    <div class="dElement">
        <div class="d_option">Phone</div>
        <div class="d_value"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="strblock rouded_3px infobox">
    <div class="dElement">
        <div class="d_option">Thu—Fri</div>
        <div class="d_value">11:00—19:00</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="strblock rouded_3px infobox">
    <div class="dElement">
        <div class="d_option">Pricing</div>
        <div class="d_value">40 USD</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="strblock rouded_3px infobox">
    <div class="dElement">
        <div class="d_option">Address</div>
        <div class="d_value">0.2km from Historic U.S. 66, Seligman, AZ 86337, USA</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="strblock rouded_3px infobox">
    <div class="dElement">
        <div class="d_option">Coordinates</div>
        <div class="d_value">
            35.52890, -113.23200<br>
            N35°31'44", W113°13'55"
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```css
#blocks_wrapper .strblock { float: left; margin-bottom: 3px; overflow: hidden; }
#blocks_wrapper .infobox { width: 19%; padding: 3px; }
#blocks_wrapper .infobox .dElement .d_option { display: inline-block; width: 90px; overflow: hidden; font-weight: bold; }
#blocks_wrapper .infobox .dElement .d_value { display: inline-block; width: 155px; vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: Can you create a simplified version of your situation, on jsFiddle or Codepen or jsBin?

Comment: Otherwise your question will be of very little help to others.

Comment: @watson Sure, why not, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late, but maybe this will help someone.
http://masonry.desandro.com

Comment: please elaborate your answer, don't just post a link